# Django - how to use messages for built-in views

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

i transfered my login view from class based views to built-in views which is : `django.contrib.auth.views.login`

before that ; i ve been using django messages in my views.py.

but i dont know how to do that under built-in views.

here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^admin/logout', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout'),
)
```

and what i want in my login.html :

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div id="notice" align="center">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% ifequal message.tags 'ERROR' %}
        <div id="notice" align="center">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

where and how can i define messages ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you set up messages properly, it should be available in your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

Comment: but i need to define those message's contents in somewhere?

Comment: If you are using the Django Login Form, the error messages will be defined. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py